# AWS S3 server access logging doesn't register getobject requests from Java SDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, logging, aws-sdk

I'm writing a Java program that uploads a file to a Amazon S3 bucket and reads the same file several times then tries to get the log of the readings. I also have Amazon CLI installed so the authentication is done using CLI.

The code I wrote to active logging in the source bucket(I'm the owner) is the following:

```java
PutBucketLoggingRequest logRequest = 
                PutBucketLoggingRequest
                .builder()
                .bucket(sourcebucket)
                .bucketLoggingStatus(
                        BucketLoggingStatus
                        .builder()
                        .loggingEnabled(
                                LoggingEnabled
                                .builder()
                                .targetBucket(destinationbucket)
                                .targetPrefix("")
                                .build())
                        .build())
                .build();
PutBucketLoggingResponse logRes = s3Client.putBucketLogging(logRequest);
```

I've noticed that the logs that appeared in my destination bucket don't have the type of operations of REST.GET.OBJECT(I waited more than 5 days), instead have something like REST.HEAD.OBJECT, GET.OBEJCT_ACL, GET.VERSIONING and other stuffs. But if I login to the S3 website and open the file from my browser then it already appear logs with the type REST.GET.OBJECT.

I use the following code to read the file:

```java
GetObjectRequest getObjectRequest = 
            GetObjectRequest
            .builder()
            .bucket(targetbucket).key(filekey)
            .responseCacheControl("no-cache")
            .build();
            
GetObjectResponse getRes = s3Client.getObject(getObjectRequest, path);
```

I thought it was the server caching that caused this, but even I put "no-cache" in the request the problem still isn't solved.

Can anyone help me with this situation? Is there anything wrong with my code that causes this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your question is NOT Clear. Is your issue how to read and display the Log file OR if the log file does not have the expected content.

Comment: My answered assume 1. I am not sure why your log file has different content.

Comment: @smac2020 Yeah that is the problem I'm trying to figure out because the code to activate logging and retrieve objects seems fine and I also don't understand why the GET operation doesn't appear on the log

Comment: Do you read the object's _content_? If not, what happens when you do that, rather than just call `getObject()`?

Comment: @kdgregory I tried to modify my code in order to get the byte stream of the file content and print it to the console, but even after doing this change, I'm still not able to get logs that have the GET.OBJECT operation. The operations in the logs are GET.PUBLIC_ACCESS_BLOCK, GET.POLICY_STATUS, GET.ACL and HEAD.BUCKET. So for me this is very strange since I've only made API calls of get object.

Comment: Those actions seem very strange; I wouldn't expect any of them to be associated with a `GetObject` request. I'm afraid I can't provide any more ideas.